# Прошу проверить правильность нормализации таблицы до 3 формы

Tags: sql, база-данных, нормализация-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои данные в базе будут выглядеть так. Я как понимаю, что бы привести к 3 форме нормализации, мне нужно убрать повторения значений во второй таблице, но как это сделать? Может быть такое, что таблица уже в нормальном состоянии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы привести ваши отношения к третьей нормальной форме, вам
надо выделить языки и типы граждан в отдельные отношения.  Например:

```
languages
=========

 id |   name
----+-----------
  1 | russian
----+-----------
  2 | ukrainian
```

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, но ведь тогда вторая таблица у меня будет ссылаться на строки из тех что вы предлогаете (по айди). И будет тоже самое дублирование данных, или нет?

Comment: Суть не в дублировании, а в разделении сущностей.  Предположим, завтра вам скажут добавить помимо названия языка его код (`ru`, `uk`, итд.).  Вам придётся держать этот код там же, в «гражданах», хотя к гражданам код языка не имеет никакого отношения.  Не говоря уже о возможности рассинхрона данных.

Comment: То есть я выношу citizen_types и languages в две новые таблицы(итого их будет 4), и во второй таблице у меня будут строки по типу: city_id: 1, citizen_type: 1, language: 2, quantity: 1200000 и т.д. Верно?

Comment: Да, именно так.